# How to randomly choose screen positions for drawing same bitmap

Tags: c, math, random, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to draw a 20x20 size bitmap at random positions on the screen. I want that the bitmaps should not overlap each other and should be scattered uniformly.

For accomplishing this, I am generating the positions as below -

```
void function() {
   int bitmap_size = 20*20;
   int i, width = 320, height = 480;
   int numslots = width*height/bitmap_size;

   int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*numslots);
   for(i=0; i<numslots; i++)
      array[i] = i;

   // Randomize pixel indices
   for(i=0; i<numslots; i++) {
      int x = (rand()%(numslots-i)) + i;
      swap(array+i, array+x);
   }

   // Generate positions for 20 bitmaps
   for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
      int pos = array[i];
      pos *= bitmap_size;
      int y = pos / height;
      int x = pos % width;
      printf("%d, %d\n", x, y);
   }

   free(array);
}
```

However, when i run this code, the pixel positions are somewhat cluttered as you can see from the sample output (x, y) below for 20 positions -

```
240, 85
160, 255
80, 37
240, 115
80, 280
160, 118
0, 223
80, 170
80, 147
240, 45
0, 253
160, 225
160, 261
0, 66
80, 230
80, 30
0, 236
80, 27
160, 238
0, 200
```

3 positions are at x=240, 5 positions are at x=160 and x=0 each and 7 positions are at x=80. How to generate more uniformly scattered locations for the bitmaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060478/how-to-randomly-but-evenly-distribute-nodes-on-a-plane/24947180#24947180

Comment: uniformly scattered?

Answer (score 0):

1. Divide the entire screen to tiles:

(0, 0) - (20, 20) Tile #0 
(21, 0) - (21, 20) Tile #1 
... 
(299, 0) - (319, 20) Tile #14 
(0, 20) - (20, 40) Tile #15 
... 
(299, 459) - (319, 478) Tile #383

2. Create an array of size 384, such that arr[i] = i
   int arr[384]; 
   for (int i = 0; i < 384; i++) {
       arr[i] = i;
   }
3. Randomize the contents of the array:
   void randomize(int arr[], int size) {
       for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i-- {
           int place = rand(i);
           swap(&arr[i], &arr[place]);
       }
   }
4. Use contents of the first 3 cells of the array to choose tiles you set in step 1

Comment: `for (int i = size; i > 0; i-- {` will index outside the array when you use `&arr[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, modified the answer.