# How can I Check all the Points in a 2D Graph for Distance and Make Sure None are Too Close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, procedural-generation

I want to create and return a randomized set of 2-element tuples that represent points on a 2D graph. My problem is that I want each point to be at least a certain distance away from each other. This should be according to the value of the minDistance parameter in the function below.

I can't think of a way to go through a set and check every single point for distance while replacing points that aren't far enough away. How can I accomplish that?

NOTE: The graph is 90 points in length and 160 points in width.

Here is my function so far:

```
def makeTiles(num, xBounds, yBounds, minDistance):
"""
Creates and returns a set of points.

:param num: int
    The number of points to be returned.
:param xBounds: tuple of 2 ints
    The first element is the minimum an x-value should be.
    The second element is the maximum an x-value should be.
:param yBounds: tuple of 2 ints
    The first element is the minimum an y-value should be.
    The second element is the maximum an y-value should be.
:param minDistance: int
    The minimum distance that should occur between points.
:return: set of tuples
    The set of points that will be created.
"""
tileSet = set()

for n in range(num):
    x = r.randint(xBounds[0], xBounds[1])
    y = r.randint(yBounds[0], yBounds[1])
    tileSet.add((x, y))

tempSet = tileSet.copy()
distances = set()
for t1 in tempSet:
    for t2 in tileSet:
        distances.add(m.sqrt((t1[0] - t2[0]) ** 2 + (t1[1] - t2[1]) ** 2))
        for d in distances:
            if d < minDistance:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly but evenly distribute nodes on a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060478/how-to-randomly-but-evenly-distribute-nodes-on-a-plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), they allow for better performance in this kind of check.
Other than this, there is no way except checking the distance from every point to every other point in you Graph.

Also make sure that when you are comparing points, you dont check a point against itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an algorithm on my own.

For each point that I want to have I add all the points necessary to make a square around said point. I add these points and the original point to a temporary set and add a new point while making sure it's not in the temporary set. Then I just loop however many times I need to.

This isn't the fastest way of doing it, but it works.

```
def makeTiles():
"""
Creates and returns a set of points.

Preconditions:
    There is enough space within the area defined by xBounds and yBounds.

Algorithm:
1    Create a random point.
2    Add the point to tileSet and distanceSet.
3    Add all points within minDistance to distanceSet.
4    Create another random point.
5    while this point is in distanceSet.
6        Change the location of the point.
7    Add the point to tileSet and distanceSet.
8    Add all points within minDistance to distanceSet.
9    Continue looping from line 4 for num amount of times.

:return: set of tuples
    The set of points that will be created.
"""
tileSet = set()
distanceSet = set()

x = r.randint(KEEP_X[0], KEEP_X[1])
y = r.randint(KEEP_Y[0], KEEP_Y[1])

tileSet.add((x, y))

for t in tileSet:
    distanceSet.add((t[0], t[1]))
    for m1 in range(1, KEEP_DIST):
        for m2 in range(1, KEEP_DIST):
            distanceSet.add((x + m2, y + m1))
            distanceSet.add((x - m2, y - m1))
            distanceSet.add((x + m2, y - m1))
            distanceSet.add((x - m2, y + m1))
            distanceSet.add((x, y + m1))
            distanceSet.add((x, y - m1))
            distanceSet.add((x - m2, y))
            distanceSet.add((x + m2, y))

for n in range(KEEP_NUM):
    x = r.randint(KEEP_X[0], KEEP_X[1])
    y = r.randint(KEEP_Y[0], KEEP_Y[1])
    while (x, y) in distanceSet:
        x = r.randint(KEEP_X[0], KEEP_X[1])
        y = r.randint(KEEP_Y[0], KEEP_Y[1])
    print("(x, y)", (x, y))
    tileSet.add((x, y))
    distanceSet.add((x, y))
    for m1 in range(1, KEEP_DIST):
        for m2 in range(1, KEEP_DIST):
            distanceSet.add((x + m2, y + m1))
            distanceSet.add((x - m2, y - m1))
            distanceSet.add((x + m2, y - m1))
            distanceSet.add((x - m2, y + m1))
            distanceSet.add((x, y + m1))
            distanceSet.add((x, y - m1))
            distanceSet.add((x - m2, y))
            distanceSet.add((x + m2, y))
```